# Connect to EC2 AWS mongoDB server using PHP from Godaddy

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I have setup a Bitnami EC2 mongoDB server. It is running, I can connect to it locally and I have inserted some documents and I am able to see my database and the documents using MongoDB Compass (through SSH tunnel). In the security group of my EC2 instance I allow all traffic from all ports (for test purposes). I have commented out also the bind_ip from the mongod.config file. However when running the following code

```
<?php
$key = '1234';
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://xx.xxx.xx.xxx", array("username" => $bitnami", 
"password" => $key));
?>
```

I get the following error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017: Connection refused'"

I have searched for possible answers and asked a similar question in stackoverflow before but it solved my problem only partially. I know the MongoClient command is deprecated but using the MongoDB\Driver\Manager I also cannot connect and no error message is shown. I hope somebody can help me with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you make sure you allow the incoming ports in your security groups for EC2?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/

Comment: Yes I allow traffic from all ports... but does not solve the problem. I am already searching days on this without success.

Comment: if you run within the ec2, does it connect?

Comment: Yes I ssh'd to my ec2 and I could connect locally to localhost and I added some documents.

Comment: I could connect from my computer using $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://xx.xx.xxx.xxx", array("username" => "root", "password" => "password")); But I cannot connect from my GoDaddy server: I get connection refused.. how is it possible it works from my computer but not from my GoDaddy server??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Godaddy restricts outgoing connection ports so you cannot connect from Godaddy to EC2.

Other useful references:

https://godaddy.pissedconsumer.com/they-can-t-even-open-a-port-for-outgoing-connections-ridiculous-20140923537475.html

https://www.godaddy.com/community/Developer-Cloud-Portal/vps-outbound-port-restriction/td-p/3770

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! I also spend around 200 euro for a 2 year plan with GoDaddy only to find out now thanks to you that it is not possible to connect, what a waste of money and time! Thanks for letting me know.